# How to test file upload in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, junit

I have a controller that takes in a file as part of the parameter. I'm wondering how can I test this?

my controller action:

```
def save () {
  def colorInstance = new Color(params.color)
  CommonsMultipartFile file = request.getFile('color.filename')
  fileUploadService.upload(colorInstance, file, "foldername")
  if (requestInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    withFormat {
      html {redirect(action: "list") }
      js {render "test"}
    }
  }
}
```

I've started with something like this:...

```
import org.junit.Before
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(ColorController)
@Mock(Color)
class ColorControllerTests {

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        controller.fileUploadService = new FileUploadService
    }
}
```

**Question**

- I can't figure out how to test the `CommonsMultipartFile` for file upload.
- Also, this test case will sit in `unit` test folder. How can I execute it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the request will be `multipart` during file upload, the actual request servlet would be `MultipartHttpServletRequest`. For unit test case, `mock` the same and use it as the `request` in `controller`. On successful mocking you should be able to `addFile` in tests and `getFile` in `action`.

```
import org.junit.Before
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(ColorController)
@Mock(Color)
class ColorControllerTests {

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        controller.fileUploadService = new FileUploadService
        //Mock MultipartHttpServletRequest somethign like below
        controller.metaClass.request = mockFor(MultipartHttpServletRequest).createMock()
    }

    void testFileUpload(){
         //Add a mock multipart file to request
         controller.request.addFile(new MockMultipartFile('myFile', 'IronMan3.jpg', 'image/jpeg', "1234567" as byte[]))

         //call the controller action
         //assert response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using Grails 2.4, and you can simply use `GrailsMockMultipartFile` and `request.addFile` method in your unit test.

This code works on Grails 2.4.4, with Spock testing framework:

Controller side:

```
class FileUploadController {

    def upload() {
        def multipartFile = request.getFile('requestParamName')
        if (multipartFile.empty) {
            flash.message = 'Error: file cannot be empty'
            render(view: 'upload')
            return
        }

        // do something now with your file
    }
}
```

Unit test side:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockMultipartFile
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(FileUploadController)
class FileUploadControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "upload should add flash error message if empty file in request"() {
        given:
        def multipartFile = new GrailsMockMultipartFile('requestParamName', 'someExcelFile.xls', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', new byte[0])
        request.addFile(multipartFile)

        when:
        controller.upload()

        then:
        assertEquals('Error: file cannot be empty', flash.message)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. The following code did:

```
import org.junit.Before
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartHttpServletRequest
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile

@TestFor(ColorController)
class ColorControllerTests {

    def mockRequest

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        mockRequest = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest()
        controller.metaClass.request = mockRequest

        // your service here
        controller.fileUploadService = new FileUploadService
    }

    void testFileUpload(){
         //Add a mock multipart file to request
         mockRequest.addFile(new MockMultipartFile('myFile', 'IronMan3.jpg', 'image/jpeg', "1234567" as byte[]))

         //call the controller action
         //assert response
    }
}
```