# mockRequest doesn't work in grails 2.x

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking, grails-2.0

I have a code which get's the file from request object

```
        if (!request.getFile('uploadFile').isEmpty()) {
        ...
    }
```

To test this I used mockRequest. I have written this unit test case in grails 1.3.7 which worked fine but the same fails after upgrading it to grails 2.2.4

```
        mockRequest.metaClass.getFile = { file ->
        return new MockMultipartFile('uploadFile', new byte[0])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Match signature while using metaClass. Use `String file ->`.
- Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16513804/2051952) can help in any ways.

FYI. `mockRequest` is no more used from Grails 2.x. You can use `request` instead.